# Pentaho Server: Uploaded KTR files not syncing up in browser

Tags: pentaho, kettle

1. I started my Pentaho Server
2. Created a Folder
3. Uploaded some .ktr files to that folder

**Prob 1**: When I refresh, it says there are no files. When I view the same folder from `Kettle` it does show me the files

**Prob 2**: Also when I delete a .ktr file from `Kettle` view, browser still says its present, and browser allows me to delete those files (meaning kettle is not deleting files?).

**Prob 3**: From browser I can create folders, but from `Kettle` I cannot create folders.

[image]

Comment: Which version of pentaho?
Enterprise Edition or community?

Comment: Community Server

Comment: in community there are certain issues which gets resolves by simply re-starting it.

Comment: restart not helping